# Is it possible to create GraphQL server that accepts `GraphQLRequest` and produces `GraphQLResponse`?

Tags: graphql, quarkus

In older versions of Quarkus (`2.X`) I was able to have following endpoint:

```java
@Path("/graphql")
public class GraphQLResource {

    private final GraphQLManager graphQLManager;

    public GraphQLResource() {
        this.graphQLManager = new GraphQLManager();
    }

    @POST
    public GraphQLResponse graphQL(GraphQLRequest request) {
        return graphQLManager.execute(request);
    }
}
```

In this class I had entire GraphQL manager under the control including the schema generation, resolvers and so on. Now I upgraded to Quarkus 3.x that uses `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` and `quarkus-smallrye-graphql` and I'm not able to make it work again. The single form of GraphQL endpoint that works for me is the endpoint that accepts and produces statically compiled DTOs like this:

```java
@Path("/graphql")
@GraphQLApi
public class GraphQLResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Query
    public EchoResponse echo(String message) {
        return new EchoResponse(message);
    }

    public static class EchoResponse {
        private final String message;

        public EchoResponse(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have enough details about the original use case that you're describing, so it's hard to tell why it has stopped working. The `GraphQLResponse` and `GraphQLRequest` classes are something that you created yourself and you just expect Quarkus to convert them from/to Jackson? What is the error that you're seeing with that now?

The latter example is what Quarkus supports through the `smallrye-graphql` extension and should be preferred, except that you're mixing JAX-RS and MicroProfile GraphQL annotations. There's no need to make that class a REST endpoint at all.

Comment: The original implementation that worked with Quarkus 2.X was as follows: https://github.com/FgForrest/HttpServerEvaluationTest/blob/main/quarkus_server/src/main/java/one/edee/oss/http_server_evaulation_test/server/quarkus/GraphQLResource.java ... it used `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` and accepted my own `GraphQLManager`, which I had full control over.

Now it prints the error:

```
2023-05-30 09:21:51,628 WARN  [io.sma.graphql] (main) SRGQL010000: Schema is null, or it has no operations. Not bootstrapping SmallRye GraphQL
```

Comment: The GraphQL schema is initialized though: https://github.com/FgForrest/HttpServerEvaluationTest/blob/main/graphql/src/main/java/one/edee/oss/http_server_evaulation_test/graphql/GraphQLProvider.java but the `GraphQLResource` endpoint constructor is never called.

Comment: Hold on, it seems to me that you've added the `quarkus-smallrye-graphql` extension, but you're not actually using anything  from it, hence the SRGQL010000 message. That extension is for declaring GraphQL APIs using annotations from the MicroProfile GraphQL spec, but it looks like you're implementing your own wrapper over classes from the graphql-java library. That makes me think you should not be adding that extension, only the graphql-java library directly?!

Comment: Honestly, there is too much magic involved for me. If I remove `quarkus-smallrye-graph` and leave only MicroProfile GraphQL spec and leave the method signature:

```java
@POST
    public GraphQLResponse graphQL(GraphQLRequest request) {
        return graphQLManager.execute(request);
    }
```

... who will translate the HTTP request to a GraphQLRequest and GraphQLResponse back to the HTTP response?

Comment: In case of different servers I had it fully under the control - see for example https://github.com/FgForrest/HttpServerEvaluationTest/blob/isolated-modules/netty_server/src/main/java/one/edee/oss/http_server_evaulation_test/server/netty/GraphQLHandler.java#L49, but in case of Quarkus everything seems annotation based and the plugins wrap the method with necessary gluecode. But I don't know what I need here to make it work.

Comment: From my understanding you don't actually need anything from the MicroProfile GraphQL API, so you can leave out the dependency completely. If you're depending on the graphql-java library, you can add that directly (the `quarkus-smallrye-graphql` extension brings it in transitively). And then yes, if you have your own logic that can transform `GraphQLRequest` to `GraphQLResponse` and these classes are translatable to JSON, then it should work.

Comment: You are right - this `pom.xml` version works as before: https://github.com/FgForrest/HttpServerEvaluationTest/blob/isolated-modules/quarkus_server/pom.xml

I don't know what and where the HTTP request/response is translated to these objects, but it seems to work. I was misguided by the articles about graphql setup in Quarkus and added libraries that complicated the situation.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, the POM must not contain Smallrye-GraphQL library. The working `pom.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>http_server_evaulation_test</artifactId>
        <groupId>one.edee.oss</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>http_server_evaulation_test_quarkus_server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.0.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>one.edee.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>http_server_evaulation_test_graphql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Thanks go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/615104/jan-marti%c5%a1ka